# Reloading <div> disables tooltip

Tags: javascript

I have code loading from a database that refreshes every xx seconds.
So I am refreshing just the div every xx seconds.

When I click the code/button it shows a tooltip with 'text copied'.

However when the page reloads the tooltip stops working.
Using :             `$("#here").load(" #here > *");`
works but it starts to bug out

Is my tooltip wrong or my refreshing code?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            /*$("#here").load(" #here > *");*/
            $('#here').load('test.html');
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.test').tooltip({ title: "Text", trigger: "mDown", delay: { hide: 100 } });
    });
</script>

<div style="margin:50px;">
    <div id="here">
        <button class="test">test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After reload you must re-initialize your tooltip as it's not listening for DOM changes.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function initTooltip() {
        $('.test').tooltip({ title: "Text", trigger: "mDown", delay: { hide: 100 } });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        initTooltip();

        setInterval(function () {
            $('#here').load('test.html #here > *');
            initTooltip();
        }, 3000);
    });
</script>

<div style="margin:50px;">
    <div id="here">
        <button class="test">test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```